# Combine two parent-child transformations for common link

Tags: transforms, ros-kinetic, camera, quaternion, coordinate

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to connect two tf trees via a known link by following the advice from @tfoote [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/322015/tf-static_transform_publisher-removes-link-instead-of-linking-two-tf-trees/?answer=322017#post-id-322017). One link belongs to the robot tf tree and the other belongs to a camera tf tree that is not part of the robot urdf. `ar_tracker_alvar` is providing the known link from the camera to a link defined in the robot urdf. I have looked up the transformations using `tf2_ros`, where `robot_link_1` and `alvar_link_1` share the same point in space:

```
tf_buffer =tf.Buffer()
known_transform_1 = tf_bufffer.lookup_transform('robot_link_1' , 'base_link', rospy.Time.now(), rospy.Duration(1.0))
known_transform_2 = tf_bufffer.lookup_transform('alvar_link_1' , 'camera_link', rospy.Time.now(), rospy.Duration(1.0))
```

I have added the position information to get a new combined xyz transformation:

```
t = TransformStamped()
t1 = known_transform_1.transform.translation
t2 = known_transform_2.transform.translation
t.x = t1.x + t2.x
t.y = t1.x + t2.x
t.z = t1.x + t2.x
```

The resulting vector appears to be the correct length from the camera to the robot base. Next, my understanding of how to combine the rotation information is as follows:

```
q_robot = known_transform_1.transform.rotation
q_camera = known_transform_2.transform.rotation
rotation = tf.transformations.quaternion_multiply(q_robot, q_camera)
```

I am using this information to send to a broadcaster to provide a link between the two trees:

```
tf_broadcaster = tf.TransformBroadcaster()
t_broadcaster.sendTransform(t)
```

Combining the quaternions, however, does not work as expected.

[image: image description]

As you can see, the rotation is off.

I have tried changing the placement of ar tags as well as other analytical solutions, but I appear to be missing a critical piece of information for how to combine the rotation components.

How do I perform the translation to link the two trees?

You can see in the visualization that the robot and camera appear to be aligned as expected.

For more context, below is the outcome of a tag placed in a different location:

[image: image description]

[image: image description]

EDIT:

Trying the suggestion by @janindu to directly link `robot_link_1` and `camera_link` results in a similar situation where the tf_tree is completed but the translation is still incorrect at a different pose. See the following:

[image: image description]

https://answers.ros.org/question/322015/tf-static_transform_publisher-removes-link-instead-of-linking-two-tf-trees/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/322317/combine-two-parent-child-transformations-for-common-link/) by [ceres](https://answers.ros.org/users/38931/ceres/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86 on 2019-05-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are trying to connect the tf trees at by adding the `base_link` -> `camera_link`. However, given that `alvar_link_1` and `robot_link_1` refer to the same frame, you can make the problem simpler by connecting the tf trees by adding the `robot_link_1` -> `camera_link` transformation.

For that, get

```
known_transform = tf_bufffer.lookup_transform('alvar_link_1' , 'camera_link', rospy.Time.now(), rospy.Duration(1.0))
```

and publish the **same** transformation with

```
parent_frame = robot_link_1
child_frame = camera_link
```

---

Originally posted by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) with karma: 849 on 2019-05-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ceres](https://answers.ros.org/users/38931/ceres/) on 2019-05-01**:
Thanks, but `alvar_link_1` and `robot_link_1` are not part of the same frame. They refer to the same point in the real world, but in two separate tf_trees. This is why I need to join their parent elements (`base_link` and `camera_link` using the transformations. I attempted to directly join them in a prior question that I [referenced](https://answers.ros.org/question/322015/tf-static_transform_publisher-removes-link-instead-of-linking-two-tf-trees/?answer=322017#post-id-322017), which didn't work.

**Comment by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) on 2019-05-01**:
I saw that question. However, if **both** `alvar_link_1` and `robot_link_1` **consistently** refer to the same point in space, you can add the transformation as I have mentioned.

**Comment by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) on 2019-05-01**:
In that question you have tried to join `alvar_link_1` with `robot_link_1` and you faced the problem of having multiple parents for a frame, which is not allowed in ROS. However, now you are actually computing `robot_link_1` -> `camera_link` **assuming** that `alvar_link_1` -> `robot_link_1` is a zero rotation zero translation transformation (they refer to the same frame in space).

**Comment by [ceres](https://answers.ros.org/users/38931/ceres/) on 2019-05-01**:
I tried what you are describing again as a sanity check, and the tf tree appears to be connected using `rqt_tf_tree`, but Rviz shows `No transform from [camera_link] to [robot_link_1]`.

**Comment by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) on 2019-05-01**:
That sounds like a problem with publishing rate. How fast do you publish the `robot_link_1` -> `camera_link` transformation?

**Comment by [ceres](https://answers.ros.org/users/38931/ceres/) on 2019-05-01**:
Wouldn't I need to also publish a zero rotation zero translation transformation for `alvar_link_1` and `robot_link_1` if I wanted to directly compute `robot_link_1` and `camera_link`?

**Comment by [ceres](https://answers.ros.org/users/38931/ceres/) on 2019-05-01**:
The Rate is set to `1.0`. What should it be set at?

**Comment by [ceres](https://answers.ros.org/users/38931/ceres/) on 2019-05-01**:
I can confirm that setting the rate to `100.0` fixes the frame linking, but the translation is still incorrect.

**Comment by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) on 2019-05-01**:
What is the output of `rosrun tf tf_echo robot_link_1 alvar_link_1` now? When you say `alvar_link_1` and `robot_link_1` share the same point, is the expected transformation between the `alvar_link_1` and `robot_link_1` zero rotation zero translation **or** is it just zero translation?

**Comment by [ceres](https://answers.ros.org/users/38931/ceres/) on 2019-05-01**:
I think that's part of what I'm not grasping. The ar tag I would like to use is fixed to the joint of the robot, and has been written into the urdf. Shouldn't the tf lookup give me the values I need to do any rotation I need?

**Comment by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) on 2019-05-01**:
OK. This is what you need to do now.

1. When the camera detects the tag, understand the orientation of the tag pose. That is, wrt the tag, what are the XYZ axes? In RVIZ, XYZ axes correspond to the RGB arrows.
2. Check the robot URDF to see if the `robot_link_1` frame transformation correspond to the same pose.

I think the problem is that there is a rotation between the `alvar_link_1` and `robot_link_1`. If this **is** the case you can fix it in the URDF.

**Comment by [ceres](https://answers.ros.org/users/38931/ceres/) on 2019-05-01**:
It did appear to be a problem with rotation. Thanks for all the help with this.

**Comment by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) on 2019-05-01**:
Glad to be of help!